# How to place UILabel in the center of navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder, uilabel

How to place `UILabel` in the center of navigation bar in XCode 6? Is it possible at all? I can place here, for example, `UIButton`, but unable to place `UILabel`. If no, what can I do then? Place a `UIButton` with the appropriate text and make it non-clickable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `Xcode 6` if you want to put a label inside the `UINavigationBar` firstly you have to put a UIView there then put the UILabel inside the UIView (this is from the Storyboard btw).

If you do not put the `UIView` first then the `UILabel` will never get put onto the `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 9):

Create a UIView and add `UILabel` as it's subview and then set your `NavigationItem`'s titleView as previously created UIView.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
label.text = @"Hello";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[view addSubview:label];
self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
```

**Note**: Don't forget to set your own frame values to get better result.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you try `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method instead of `viewDidLoad` that was what worked for me. Cheers!